# Construct subgroup of $\mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_2}$ where both groups involved in the direct product are not subgroups of $\mathbb{Z_2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, direct-product

I am tasked in an exercise to do the following:

*Construct an example of a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_2}$ which is not of the form $K \times J$ for some $K < \mathbb{Z_2}$ and $J < \mathbb{Z_2}$*

---

So, it's my understanding that this question is asking us to construct a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_2}$ of the form $K \times J$ where either $K$ or $J$ is not a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z_2}$ correct? I know it has to have the direct product construction of $K \times J$ otherwise the elements wouldn't have the same structure, as pairs of elements from each group. This is correct? I'm a little confused at the wording, it makes it sound like we are to construct a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_2}$ which isn't constructed via the direct product construction.

With that out of the way, the only thought that comes to mind on potentially meeting this requirement is to have $K$ or $J$ be a subgroup of a larger group of modular arithmetic that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_2}$... but if it's isomorphic to the group in question then it's just labels that distinguish it from $\mathbb{Z_2}$ and is really a distinction without a difference.

The subgroups of $\mathbb{Z_2}$ are just the trivial subgroups: $\mathbb{Z_2}$ itself and $\{[0]\}$. So I don't really see how one can get a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_2}$ without having each group $K,J$ for $K \times J < \mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_2}$, be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z_2}$.

Any thoughts on how best to proceed?

Comment: Consider $$\Delta=\langle (1,1)\rangle.$$

Comment: Now, as I understand it $\Delta$ is the subgroup generated by the element $(1,1)$. In other words $$\Delta = \langle (1,1) \rangle = \{ (1,1)^{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$$ But are the elements $(1,1)$ representatives of the congruence class $[1] \in \mathbb{Z_2}$? If so then wouldn't we have $$\Delta = \langle [1] \rangle \times \langle [1] \rangle = \{ (1,1), (0,0)\} = \mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_2}$$ Where $\langle [1] \rangle < \mathbb{Z_2}$? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: No, $$\Delta=\{([0], [0]), ([1],[1])\}.$$ Compute it, but note that $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$ is abelian, so you require *multiples*, not powers.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance but I'm still quite confused. I see that $$\Delta \neq \mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_2} = \{([0],[0]),([1],[0]),([0],[1]),([1],[1])\}$$ So $\Delta$ is a proper subgroup. But I am still seeing $\Delta$ as being the direct product of the subgroup generated by $[1]$. Since $$\Delta = \{([0],[0]),([1],[1])\} = \langle [1] \rangle \times \langle [1] \rangle$$ Where $$\langle [1] \rangle = \{[0], [1]\} < \mathbb{Z_2}$$ Since $$[1] \in \mathbb{Z_2}$$

Comment: No, and here's a hint: $$2([1],[1])=(2[1],2[1]).$$

Comment: So, what you're saying is that $$\Delta = \langle ([1],[1]) \rangle = \{n([1],[1] \mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$$ And for the hint, why isn't the $2$ 'distributed' over both elements of the pair? Instead of just the first. 

Also, would $$2[1] = [1] + [1] = [0]$$ Since I'm assuming $$[1] \in \mathbb{Z_2}$$ So that we would have $$2([1],[1]) = (2[1],[1]) = ([0],[1])$$ and $$3([1],[1]) = (3[1],[1]) = ([1],[1])$$ Alternating as we iterate between even and odd multiples.

Comment: It seems you're confused by a typo of mine. (I'm sorry!) Look again: I edited my last comment.

Comment: Okay so then $$\langle ([1],[1]) \rangle = \{n([1],[1] \mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \} = \{([0],[0]),([1],[1])\}$$ Which makes sense to me why it would be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_2}$ I guess I'm just confused because it seems like $$\langle ([1],[1]) \rangle = \langle [1] \rangle \times \langle [1] \rangle$$ Where $$\langle [1] \rangle < \mathbb{Z_2}$$ And so we still would have a subgroup of the form $$K \times J$$ Where $$K < \mathbb{Z_2}, J < \mathbb{Z_2}$$ Would we not?

Comment: But $$([0],[1])\in\langle [1]\rangle \times \langle [1]\rangle=:A.$$ Indeed, $A\cong \Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$ because $$\langle [1]\rangle =\Bbb Z_2.$$

Comment: Oh I see. So the construction for $\Delta$ would in fact not be $$\langle ([1],[1]) \rangle = \langle [1] \rangle \times \langle [1] \rangle$$ Since $\Delta$ doesn't have as an element either $([1],[0])$ nor $([0],[1])$? 

What would the constituent groups be for the direct product construction of $\Delta$? I.e., what would $K,J$ as in the question be? Or would it just be irreducible and as fundamental as possible the way it's written above?

Comment: Here $\Delta$ is what is known as the *diagonal subgroup*. It is not the direct product of any nontrivial subgroups.

Comment: This is a standard exercise and I think you would benefit from filling in the details yourself. Don't be deterred if you don't get it right away.

Comment: Oh, that is very interesting indeed. I'll have to do some further reading on that. I want to say thank you very much for your patience and your help. I wish there was some other way to offer some recognition or reward beyond just the 'points' system on this site as I see you on so many of my posts, consistently offering great guidance and wisdom, so selflessly. The world needs more people like you @Shaun in it. Be well and enjoy your night!

Comment: That means a lot. Thank you, and you're very welcome!